# What is the Typescript type for a route map object in hookrouter?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, hookrouter

How do I replace any for hookrouter??

```
type RouteMap = Record<string, (props?: any) => JSX.Element>;
                                        ^^^
```

Full Code

```
import {
  useRoutes,
  usePath,
} from 'hookrouter'

//// HOW DO I REPLACE any???
type RouteMap = Record<string, (props?: any) => JSX.Element>;

const routes: RouteMap = {
  '/': () => <LandingPage />,
  '/asdf': () => <ASDF />,
  '/list/:userId': ({ id }) => <MainPage userId={id} />,
};

function MainApp(): JSX.Element | null {
  const routeResult = useRoutes(routes);
  const userProfile = useUserProfileState();
...
...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "replace any"? Any is a typescript word that means that props can be anything. I'm guessing you have an "any is evil" linting rule?

Comment: How do we properly type props will be a good question...

Answer (score 3):

The [definitions for this package](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/d945f8fb1e8767b1412e84f53cb49b8cd211fc0d/types/hookrouter/index.d.ts#L61) are extremely loose.  They describe the props as `{[key: string]: any;}` and allow your route render functions to return anything.

`Record<string, string>` is one step stricter.  This would describe the props in a vague sense since URL segments are always `string`.

This is better than `any` but it doesn't reflect the fact that your components each have different props.

---

There is actually a mistake in your current code and it would be great if we could get Typescript to see that.

```
'/list/:userId': ({ id }) => <MainPage userId={id} />
```

Since the URL param is `userId`, the props get `userId` **not** `id`.

We can achieve very strict typing using the new Typescript template literal types.  We can create a `ExtractSlugs` utility type which finds all of the slugs in a route string.

```
type ExtractSlugs<T extends string> = 
  // matches from : to / 
  T extends `${string}:${infer Slug}/${infer After}` ? Slug | ExtractSlugs<After> : 
  // matches from : to end
  T extends `${string}:${infer Slug}` ? Slug : 
  never;

type A = ExtractSlugs<'/list/:userId/:other'>  // type: "userId" | "other"
type B = ExtractSlugs<'/list/:userId'> // type: "userId"
type C = ExtractSlugs<'/list'> // type: never
```

Those should be the keys of our props object, and the values should be `string`.

```
type RouteMap<Keys extends string> = {
  [K in Keys]: (props: Record<ExtractSlugs<K>, string>) => JSX.Element | null
}
```

In order to create an object where the keys depend on the values, we need to use an identify function.  This allows us to enforce a restriction on all key-value pairs.

```
const createRoutes = <Keys extends string>(map: RouteMap<Keys>) => map;
```

Now we get an error! *"Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Record<"userId", string>'"*

```
createRoutes({
  '/list/:userId': ({ id }) => <MainPage userId={id} />,
})
```

But this is fine:

```
const routes = createRoutes({
  '/': () => <LandingPage />,
  '/asdf': () => <ASDF />,
  '/list/:userId': ({ userId }) => <MainPage userId={userId} />,
})
```

If your pages are function components then you should be able to pass them directly too.

```
const routes = createRoutes({
  '/': LandingPage,
  '/asdf': ASDF,
  '/list/:userId': MainPage,
})
```

If you tried to use `MainPage` for a route which did not have `:userId` in the key then you would get an error.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/m3Axkw)